# Convert String to Long

Tags: java, string, long-integer

Is it possible to convert a String to long without using java's built in function?

For instance:

```
String s = "35";
long ans = Long.parseLong(s);
```

How can you carry out the same task without using java's `Long.parseLong function`

Comment: Why would you want to? Is this homework? If so, please add the homework tag.

Comment: You could write your own parser

Comment: By looking at the source code for parseLong() ;-)

Comment: Yes; you can rewrite `parseLong()`.

Comment: Yes you need to treat the String as a primitive character array. Then you need to construct a Long based on the index values.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is possible. Just do it the traditional way. Use String.charAt() to get each character from the units place onwards and then multiply by a factor of 10 and keep summing till you reach the start of the string. Of course, you have to take care of special cases.

Answer (score 1):

Yes:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "35";
    long ans = parse(s);
}

public final static long parse(CharSequence d) {
    int l = d.length();
    boolean n= d.charAt(0) == '-';
    long v = 0;
    int p = n?1:0;
    do {
        v *= 10;
        int i = d.charAt(p) - 48;
        if (i < 0 | i > 9)
            throw new NumberFormatException(d+"");
        v += i;
        p++;
    } while (l > p);
    return n?-v:v;
}
```